# For each different folder how to make a different .iso?

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal

I have 12 folders

```
one
two
three
four
...
```

I wish to make something like this

```
one.iso
two.iso
...
```

but I don't know what command can I use. Any suggestion?

with Mkisofs you can use

```
mkisofs –o backup.iso /home/tin/Documents/backup
```

but this command is only for 1 folder: 1 iso file but I want 12 folders:12 iso files

Comment: Can't you use a loop? `for d in */; do mkisofs -o "$d.iso" "$d" ; done`

Comment: Why do you need to do this?

Comment: @pLumo make it an answer :P you need the rep >:-D

Comment: @pLumo I have this strange output, seems don't work, look here: https://imgur.com/XNXlGbB.png

Comment: pfffff @Rinzwind

Comment: @pLumo I don't understand in what folders create that .iso because I go in folders and I don't see nothing, no .iso files

Comment: Ah my fault .wait!

Comment: @pLumo mm...now I see... is inside my **zoom** folder and inside **zoom** folder but that .iso have no folder names ! Look here https://imgur.com/NzhoQEp.png

Comment: yes I know, I explain that in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the comments I told you to run:

```bsh
for d in */; do
    mkisofs -o "$d.iso" "$d"
done
```

This created hidden files `.iso` in each of the directory, because inside the loop, `$d` contains a trailing slash, and evaluates to `one/.iso` instead of the expected `one.iso`.

So, please delete these files first:

```
rm */.iso
```

---

Now (and next time) you can do the right thing directly:

Go to the parent directory of your 12 directories and make a loop:

```bsh
for d in */; do
    mkisofs -o "${d%/}.iso" "$d"
done
```

--> `${d%/}` [removes the trailing slash](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9018877).

The iso files will be next to the directories named like

```
one.iso
two.iso
...
```

Comment: Super! thank you !

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, glad to help :-)

Comment: @pLumo I think now you've cleared up the confusion, you can get rid of the top half of your answer and delete your first comment, otherwise you might make other people confused as well!